# Searching for the best practice making REST APIs

Tags: api-design

I'm currently working on the back and the front of a web app as a fun project and found something that made me ask myself question, what is the best way to return in an API a result that is wrong.

For example, when I try to login, I send a post request to my API that look something like
*https://api.foo.bar/v1/auth/login* with a JSON object that contains the user and the password.

If the login is a success, I return a 200 OK code, but if the the account don't exist or the password don't match, I return a 404 ERROR code (I don't want to dissociate account that don't exist and password that don't match).

It work really great, I just need to check the response code to know if everything worked well, but it still drop a 404 error in the console of the user, it's not really a big deal, but I was wondering if there is a better way to handle that kind of case!

I'm pretty new to "API designing" ? I guess, but I'm happy to learn more everyday.

I tried to use response code as indicator of the status in a user interaction, and was wondering if it was the best way to do it.

Comment: Try googling "API design guidelines". You may find stuff that helps e.g. https://adidas.gitbook.io/api-guidelines/

Answer (score 0):

> If the login is a success, I return a 200 OK code

**Successful login**

Yes. It is correct. You should use a 200 OK status code in this case.
Also you can include the user's authentication token or session information in the response body, allowing the user to make authorised requests.

> but if the the account the password don't match

**Invalid credentials**

In this case you should use a 401 Unauthorised status code to indicate that the client's request has invalid authentication credentials for example incorrect username or password. I also recommend to provide a clear message in the response body to inform the client about the reason for the failure.

> but if the the account don't exist

**Account doesn't exist**

In this case you should use a 404 Not Found status code to indicate that the user account as requested resource doesn't exist. I also recommend to provide a clear message in the response body to inform the client.